# With the pose between two images, how do you project a point from one scene into another?

Tags: c, opencv, computer-vision

If you have the full relative-3D values of two images looking at the same scene (relative x,y,z), along with the extrinsic/intrinsic parameters between them, how do you project the points from one scene into the other scene, in opencv?

Comment: What do you mean by "other scene"? Another camera?

Comment: Yes.  Moreso, field of view.  Two full 3D cameras looking at the same space, with a rotation and translation between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the extrinsic parameters be *R* and *t* such that camera 1 is [*I*|0] and camera 2 is [*R*|t]. So all you have to do is rotate and the translate point cloud 1 with *R* and *t* to have it in the same coordinate system as point cloud 2.

Comment: This is indeed true, but take a scenario where, say, you want to build a 3d model of a tangible object.  I can easily get one view from the first camera, and to get more information about the object, you could get a second camera and view it from a slightly different angle, getting you more points from the 3d object you are building a model of.

Comment: Yes, so all you need is the projection matrix of your virtual camera. Multiply it with a homogeneous 3D point from your cloud (which has a color associated with it), and you have your view.

Comment: Just for clarifications, what do you mean when you say "virtual" camera?  Thanks for the back and forth help, by the way.

Comment: No problem. From what I understood from your question, you have 3D data from 2 cameras. Now you want to view the scene from a third "virtual" camera (view synthesis). Is that the case, or do you want the image of a 3D point on Camera 2 observable only to Camera 1?

Comment: This would be a fair way to view it.  I just want them all projected into one space.  I assumed it would be easiest to project the points from camera 2 onto the space of camera 1.

Comment: Oh, so you want a panoramic shot of sorts? I.e. the both images merged into one large image?

Comment: Not quite.  As per my original example, where it is reconstructing the 3d scene based on multiple views of some object in 3d space.  So rather than a panoramic, I am thinking about the 3d reconstruction (I care less about the intensity image.  I wish to project the 3d points from one camera to the same space as the 3d points of the second camera)

Comment: I think I finally get it. You have the relative orientation between two cameras, but the 3D points acquired from each camera are not in the same coordinate system.

Comment: Correct!  That's the general idea

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that in general. There is an infinite number of 3D points (a line in 3d) that get mapped to one point in image space, in the other image this line won't get mapped to a single point, but a line (see [the wikipedia article on epipolar geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipolar_geometry#Epipolar_line)). You can compute the line that the point has to be on with the [fundamental matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_%28computer_vision%29).

If you do have a depth map, reproject the point into 3D - using the equations on the top of the [opencv page on camera calibration](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv-reprojectimageto3d), especially this one (it's the only one you need):
[image: Camera equations]
u and v are your pixel coordinates, the first matrix is your camera matrix (for the image you are looking at currently), the second one is the matrix containing the extrinsic parameters, Z you know (from your depth map), X and Y are the ones you are looking for - you can solve for those parameters, and then use the same equation to project the point into your other camera. You can probably use the PerspectiveTransform function from opencv to do the work for you, however I can't tell you from the top of my head how to build the projection matrix.

Comment: You can't do it in general if you have the full relative-3D values?  I realize you can't do it in general with 2D values, but doesn't this change when you know relative depth?

Comment: It does not. Unless you're saying you have a depth map from one camera also? I'd recommend you use a restricted Lucas Kanade tracking search along the epipolar line.

Comment: Yes, I have depth maps for each camera individually.  In the same vein as the microsoft kinect system

Comment: Are you using two Kinects simultaneously on the same machine? Also, are they orthogonal to each other?

Comment: @etarion: The 3D point clouds do not need to be computed. So what do you mean by "infinite number of 3D points"?

Comment: They are both on the same machine, and they are not orthogonal to one another (if they were orthogonal, there really wouldn't be any overlap).  They are viewing the same general area from slightly different angles.  With respect to the updated answer, is the right side entirely in world coordinates?  X, Y is likely world coordinates, while u, v are likely pixel coordinates.

Comment: Interesting. Doesn't the structured infrared light from both Kinects interfere with each other since it's not orthogonal?

Comment: Yeah it does.  Depending on a few restrictions, it's not as bad as you'd imagine, though.

Comment: @Jacob: The first paragraph came from when user... did not say that he does have a depth map, and then you can't project a point into another view because the 3d position of the point is ambiguous.

Comment: @user: Yes, X, Y and Z are in world coordinates (so you'd have to transform the value from your depth map first, too).

Answer (score 1):

Let the two cameras have projection matrices

P1 = K1 [ I | 0]

P2 = K2 [ R | t]

and let the depth of a given point x1 (homogeneous pixel coordinates) on the first camera be Z, the mapping to the second camera is

x2 = K2*R*inverse(K1)*x1 + K2*t/Z

There is no OpenCV function to do this. If the relative motion of the cameras is purely rotational, the mapping becomes a homography so you can use the PerspectiveTransform function.

( Ki = [fxi 0 cxi; 0 fyi cyi; 0 0 1]  )