# How to obtain rotation matrix using roll, pitch, and yaw values?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have extrinsic parameters as like this:

```
    <Ra_roll>0.213877</Ra_roll>
    <Ra_pitch>0.003699</Ra_pitch>
    <Ra_yaw>0.000555</Ra_yaw>
```

I want to get a rotation matrix, but I don't know how to calculate a rotation matrix from these roll, pitch, and yaw values.

My final goal is map color in a 2D image to 3D points in world coordinate.
So the questions are:

1. How to get rotation matrix from the roll, pitch, and yaw values?
2. How to get the scale factor between image pixels and 3D points?

Thanks.

Comment: For your first question, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21412445/4669135) for the second: you need the intrinsic calibration of the camera that was used to take the pictures, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5621309/4669135).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a rotation matrix with pitch, yaw, roll using Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412169/creating-a-rotation-matrix-with-pitch-yaw-roll-using-eigen)